# Using Windows-Server(2003/2008) in VMware for testing LDAP application in Java

Tags: java, ldap, windows-server-2008, vmware, windows-server-2003

I have made a client application for LDAP Server(especially for Microsoft AD) in java where my client application will fetch  attributes(it'll be shown) on the basis of the Entry/Base DN,Scope of Search.I have made this application in netscape and in my local system(Windows 7).

Now my plan for testing this application:

- `First,I have installed VMware-Workstation(8.0.0 build-471780),then I'll installed Windows Server(2003 or 2008) iso image through VMware.`
- `Next(will it be possible) to apply Microsoft AD services through this Windows Server version.`

I don't want to install server edition in some other system for testing.Feel free to suggest/comment about this process or correct me if I'm wrong to my approach-give inputs for the best approach for testing.

Comment: What is your intention? Authentiation or authorization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, the Windows server (and AD) doesn't mind where it's running, as long as you have sufficient resources. Install the server in VMware and then configure the AD.